# Could you use Silnet to seal a drinking water bladder?

Tags: backpacking, diy, drinking-water, hydration-bladders

I'm considering a MYOG gravity filter project but I'm not sure where to find out if [Sil Net™](http://www.mcnett.com/gearaid/silnet) can hold up under long term submersion and won't leak toxins into the water.

Is it safe?  Do you have a reference?  Got any tips on the DIY filter project?

Comment: silnet is basically silicone with a few extra things to make it easier to apply. You can use bathroom silicone joint, I would expect that one to be safe (not sure how you can make sure of that though). The question is whether it will adhere to your filter.

Comment: I learned that tile adhesive typically has a toxic fungicide. You can get NSF approved food safe silicone sealants. I need to come up with a good solvent to use too. Perhaps a high proof ethanol.

Answer (score 3):

I emailed Gear Aid, the company that makes Silnet. They didn't say it was unsafe but they did say they haven't tested it for that.

They recommended I go with a food safe adhesive. I'll probably look into that; however I'm not sure if silnylon is impregnated with non-toxic silicone either.

> We’ve not used or tested it in the manner you are describing.  You would do better with a food safe adhesive for your project.

Comment: I appreciate feedback quite a bit and I don't mind a down vote, but a comment explaining why would be helpful please.

Comment: I wouldn't trust silnylon to be completely food-safe either. I would try to find a specifically food-safe material first, and then the sealant that works on it.

Comment: Agreed. In fact, not all nylons are food safe, even if it isn't silicone impregnated. This whole project may be over my head. I may stick to DIY gear where everything stays on the outside of my body.

Comment: those guys: http://www.wazoodle.com/fabrics/food-safe-fabrics have food safe fabric. can't find any sealant yet though.

Comment: I think I could seal the seams with this: Clear Food Grade Silicone Sealant - 10.2 Oz Cartridge https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005XP5HO6/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_sUuwybENA01P7

Comment: I could use that sealant and EtOH as a solvent to make silnylon out of any food safe nylon. I could use Everclear as a solvent (you know, since I don't have a license to buy tax-free ethanol in the USA).